# How many ways to form k committee from n people such that each person belongs to m committees?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 100 people in total. In how many ways can we form 15 committees of 20 people each such that each person is on 3 committees?

I guess the number of ways to form a committee of 20 people from 100 is ${100 \choose 20}$, is that correct? Now how to incorporate the condition that each person is on 3 committees?

Any hint is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @saulspatz I'm terribly sorry about the typo. I meant 100 people and not 300. I have fixed it now.

Comment: $\binom{100}{20}$ is the number of ways to form one committee of $20$ people from among $100$.  The number of ways to choose $15$ committees would be that raised to the $15$th power, if the committees are considered distinct.

Comment: @saulspatz Ok I didn't expect it to be that big! Thanks.

Comment: Would you please add some more context?  Is this a homework problem?  If so, what course are you taking?

Comment: In effect this is counting the bipartite graphs with parts $A$ and $B$ such that $|A|=100$, $|B|=15$, each vertex in $A$ has degree $3$, and each vertex in $B$ has degree $20$.

Comment: @saulspatz I was watching the example at ~45m in this lecture -https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXwPUAIvFyg&list=PL2SOU6wwxB0uwwH80KTQ6ht66KWxbzTIo&index=22. I simply wondered how to compute the number of possibilities directly.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott This analogy is very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting lecture.  Finding the number of committees is a little contrary to his point, but here's an upper bound at least.

Since each person is on 3 committees, pretend there are 3 of each person, say 42, 42', and 42''.  Each person and their clones make up 300 potential committee members.  The number of ways to allocate them into 15 committees of 20 is
$$ {300 \choose 20}{280 \choose 20}\cdots{40 \choose 20}{20 \choose 20} = {300 \choose 20, \ldots, 20} $$
(using a multinomial coefficient) which is around $4.94 \times 10^{338}$.  This creates 15 committees of 20 and, e.g., 42, 42', and 42'' are each included.  The over-counting arises because this lets clones be on the same committee: There are even committees where "three" of the members are 42, 42', *and* 42''.  So committees with such repetition need to be removed.  However that works out, the final answer will still be huge.